# styling modal-title in bootstrap v4

Tags: flexbox, bootstrap-4

I am trying to style the content of modal title.  It will contain a center image, and two smaller columns containing 1 or 2 buttons/images.  I would like everything to align vertically and horizontally.  The size of the center images varies.  Seems like a job for flexbox.  In my actual code, the content of #headerLHS/#headerRHS/#myModalLabel is set dynamically

```
    <div class="modal-title row" id="headerBox" class="container-fluid">
      <div id="headerLHS" class="col-xs-3"><img id="lhs"/></div>
      <div id="myModalLabel" class="col-xs-6"></div>
      <div id="headerRHS" class="col-xs-3"><button id="rhs">label</button></div>
    </div>
```

So far my css is:

```
#headerLHS,#headerRHS {
    display: flex;    webkit-display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;  /* Safari */
    flex-direction:  column;
    padding: 0px;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}
```

But this doesn't work.  I seem to need styling on **#lhs** and **#rhs** but I've no idea what it should be. I've played with all sorts to flex-box markup, to no avail.  Can someone help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have equal height column, you should apply the flexbox on the parent too and set `flex-wrap: wrap;

```css
#headerBox
{
    display:flex;
    webkit-display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
} 
#headerLHS,#headerRHS {
    display: flex;    
    webkit-display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;  /* Safari */
    flex-direction:  column;
    padding: 0px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="modal-title row" id="headerBox" class="container-fluid" style="display:flex;flex-wrap: wrap;">
      <div id="headerLHS" class="col-xs-3"><button id="rhs">label</button></div>
      <div id="myModalLabel" class="col-xs-6"><img id="lhs" src="http://dummyimage.com/640x4:3" class="img-fluid"/></div>
      <div id="headerRHS" class="col-xs-3"><button id="rhs">label</button></div>
</div>
```

`